# Visual Studio 2010 UML Resources

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

I'm looking for reference material pertaining to UML support in 2010.  I've been playing around with the UML diagrams and am looking for any sort of feature lists, how-to's, what does/doesn't work, etc.  I've seen references to reverse engineering projects into UML models, don't see support for that yet.  I also understand that the code generation from UML models may not be there yet either.

I realize that as a Beta 2 it's documentation isn't anywhere close to ready, so I'm just trying to collect any reference material posted by either MS or anyone else that has been poking around with the tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the RC docs for the UML tools in VS 2010 here: [Modeling the Application](http://bit.ly/dayCXi).

You can also browse community articles linked from my Twitter page: http://twitter.com/ModelingApps

I've posted more links on [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275715/esther-fan) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great new screencast series here showing usage of the UML support in VS2010 worked through a variety of scenarios.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140807143606/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vsarch/archive/2010/07/29/channel-9-screencast-series-uml-with-vs2010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The UML Resource Page at [www.excelsoftware.com/uml.html](http://www.excelsoftware.com/uml.html) has links to tools, books, videos and white papers to learn and use UML for software design.